# How long does it take for ETH to pass from one account to another on test-net?

Tags: mist, testnets

I've used [this service](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/) to send me 1ETH on test network. Service worked, it has even given ID of transaction, but ETH has not arrived to my mist wallet in 5 mins. Is it expected to work so slow?

Thanx.

Comment: It should be instantaneous. That faucet look like is not working. You should try the other testnet www.rinkeby.io.

Comment: Isn't the only question that answer the time of a transaction, if you search maybe can found  5 or 7 more and more about faucets and how its works.

Answer (score -1):

The service is not working. [This one](http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipfs/QmTHdYEYiJPmbkcth3mQvEQQgEamFypLhc9zapsBatQW7Y/throttled_faucet.html) worked instead. Paste your wallet address in the first input box and click green button.

Comment: I don't know why you are using this service when is down, but ropsten is working fine, use the metamask faucet for obtain ether for your test.